# Importing data/database objects into C# database

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, sql-server-express

Forgive me as I'm not very proficient in C# so this question may be incorrect.  I have created a database in the App_Data folder in C# and from the Web.Config file it appears to be SQL Express.  I'm assuming that based on this entry:

```
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="ApplicationServices" 
         connectionString="data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;
         Integrated Security=SSPI;
         AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnetdb.mdf;
         User Instance=true" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

However, I don't see SQL Server Express installed on my machine.  When I click on the database in the App_Data folder, the upper left of my screen looks like this:

[image]

What I'd like to do is run some scripts I copied from a SQL Server database which will create a few stored procedures, views and functions, as well as set up the table structures.  Ideally I'd also like to import my data, which I copied from my old SQL Server into an Access db.  I can't seem to find a screen where you can do this.  If I right-click on the database and select the Create Query menu item, it wants to create a query like in Access.  I don't see any screen where I can run my script.

How do I do this in C#?

Answer (score 0):

From the Server explorer, you should be able to right-click on the database name, and select "New Query".

In the new query window that appears, paste the script that you copied from the other SQL database instance.

Once pasted, click the "Execute" button at the top of the query window.

Hope this helps.

Cheers

Comment: I get an "Unable to parse query text" error when I try that.

Comment: Then it seems your script is not properly formed.

Answer (score 0):

I got it.  You need to click on the Data menu, then Transact SQL Editor, then New Query Connection.

[image]